# Android uses the "default" method in the interface to generate apk

Tags: android, java-8, interface, default

Now there is a third-party dependency package: page
It has an interface that contains the default method :

```
public interface TempInterface {
  default String getStr() {
    return "test";
  }
}
```

And i create a module : app

There is a class in "app" that uses the above interface

```
public class AA implements TempInterface {

}
```

"build.gradle" file in "app" :

```
  dependencies {
    compileOnly project(':page')
  }
```

In the generated APK, the following classes appear:

[image: apk class]

what about *$-CC ?????

And when I decompiled the DEX file, I found that there was no such class at all:

[image]

So I'm confused about what this "* $- CC" is ??

Who can help me

the build.gradle :

[image]

Comment: What's more, if my class "AA" uses the kotlin language, everything is OK and "*$-CC" won't be generated at all.

Answer (score 1):

$-CC file is generated by d8 when the class file compile to dex file.
More details on https://mouaad.aallam.com/java-8-interface-methods-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

why you apply proguard from your `app/build.gradle`, it [obfuscates](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#obfuscate) your class and methods name so that reverse engineering is tough. that is what happens here